# Object destructuring in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, object-destructuring

Is it possible to destructure an object which comes from an function call without Typescript complaining?

**File 1**

- React Component 1

```js
...
let obj = null // <-- object initialization
...
useEffect(() => {
  obj = functionCall(...) // <-- function call that populates the object
}, [obj])
```

- React component 2

```js
const { key1, key2 } = obj // <-- object destructuring
```

Here I get the following complain from Typescript

- Property 'key1' does not exist on type 'null'.
- Property 'key2' does not exist on type 'null'.

How can I remove those warning?

Comment: Having `obj` declared and then filled in by a `useEffect` callback looks like a mistake. It may not be one, but it looks like one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for details. Depending on where that `obj` declaration is, it's either going to be re-created every time the component function runs, or it's going to be shared between all instances of the component. Both seem problematic.

Comment: The object is part of the global state of the app, set up as 'null' and I use useEffect to update the state with default value coming from  a graphql call as those default values can be changed in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a type for `obj`:

```typescript
let obj: null | {key1: sometype; key2: sometype; } = null;
```

Note that since `obj` may have the value `null`, you'll need a guard or a default value around that destructuring assignment:

```
if (obj) {
    const { key1, key2 } = obj;
}
```

or

```
const { key1, key2 } = obj ?? {key1: defaultForKey1, key2: defaultForKey2};
```

or

```
const { key1 = defaultForKey1, key2 = defaultForKey2 } = obj ?? {};
```

The difference between the last two is what happens if `obj` isn't `null` but `key1` or `key2` has the value `undefined` (if it's allowed to by the types).

Answer (score 1):

useEffect runs after your initial render - so on the first render obj will be null, and so TS is right to complain.

You need to check that obj is not null before de-structuring. Also, give it a type e.g

```js
type MyType = { key1: string; key2: number; }; // for example

let obj: MyType | null  = null;

if (obj) {
  const { key1, key2 } = obj; // OK
} else {
  // In here, obj is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-null assertion operator:

```
const { key1, key2 } = obj!;
```